# Uploading a file in c# mvc and decoding it to UTF-8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, utf-8

I am very new to MVC C#. Right now, The web app I've been working on can upload files without any issues but I cannot find a way to decode to UTF-8 and get the spanish characters right.

This is what I have so far.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

This is the code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            ...
```

When I check `content` I get accents as � (it should be é). I also include `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />` in web.config withouth success. Does anyone know how to solve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: That probably means the file isn't actually UTF8.

Comment: You're right! I changed to `Encoding.Default` and it works. I didn't check that the file is actually ANSI. Thanks

Comment: Beware that that is machine-dependent, and may not match the file.  And you now cannot handle UTF8 files.